# Repeat Tabs to for loop length

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have switch case in modal in vue
I am trying to make tabs/screens

```
            <div v-switch="tabnumber">
              <div  v-case="1">
                <form-component></form-component>
              </div>

              <div  v-case="2">
                <attribute-one-component></attribute-one-component>
              </div>

 <div  v-case="3">
                <attribute-two-component></attribute-two-component>
              </div>
              <div  v-case="4">
                <attribute-three-component></attribute-three-component>
              </div> 
              <div  v-case="5">
                <result-component
                  :product="this.product"
                  :form="this.form"
                ></result-component>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The Above code works fine but the number of screens are static which means that if i want to add new screen or tab i have to add it in the code
What i want to accomplish is to increase these screens according to length of loop

What i have tried

```
 <div v-switch="tabnumber">
          <div  v-case="1">
            <form-component></form-component>
          </div>
          <div v-for="(row,key) in attributes" :key="row.id">
          <div  v-case="key+1">
            <attribute-one-component></attribute-one-component>
          </div>
          </div>
        
          <div  v-case="5">
            <result-component
              :product="this.product"
              :form="this.form"
            ></result-component>
          </div>
        </div>
```

but it just repeats content inside that attribute-one-component on the same screen instead of creating a new screen.

Output i get after my tries

[image]

but what i want is to have these rows in new tabs such that if user clicks on one image the tab is changed to next

"LIKE A MULTI STEP FORM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `v-for` directive to the div that has `v-case` directive :

```
       <div  v-case="1">
        <form-component></form-component>
      </div>
      <div v-for="(row,key) in attributes" :key="row.id"  v-case="key+1">
        <attribute-one-component></attribute-one-component>
      </div>
```